# Cannot run Pentaho BI server on Mac

Tags: pentaho

I've been trying to install Pentaho BI Server (Community Edition) on Mac but I did not manage to make it run:

Does anyone know a good matching between the Java version and Pentaho?

When I try to run pentaho-server-ce-8.0.0.0-28 there is an issue related with Dcatalina.endorsed deprecated in Java 8 that is preventing the virtual machine to start and for the newest one shows lot of errors.

Thank you.

Comment: Pentaho 7.1 was a very stable editing.

Comment: I've re-installed tomcat and it works pretty well, the problem is the Pentaho application it self.

Comment: Pentaho has its own tomcat. You can use it with another tomcat, but then you need to reconfigure it!

Comment: Now I´m finding this error when trying to run Pentaho in Tomcat: misc-org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.PentahoSystemReadyListener: Cannot obtain JCR repository. Exiting

Comment: This error indicates a problem with the JackRabbit repository. This is  copy of the pentaho-solution in a database that can be shared over a cluster of Pentaho. On the first run, Pentaho has to built this repository. It may take 2 hours. So erase the Pentaho directory, erase also the hidden `.pentaho` directory, unzip again, restart, and watch a 2 hour video.

Comment: It run during the whole night and now is showing this message when I try to access localhost:8080/pentaho: "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."
Should I restart?

Comment: You can! And if the error persist, find a directory called .pentaho (it is hidden) in there there is a subdirectory called cashes. Empty it and restart. If the error persist delete the whole .pentaho and restart.

Comment: Any clue where is the hidden folder .pentaho folder? I´m still trying to make it run (only becase I have no chance...)

Comment: You your mac in command line. It's a unix...

Comment: Finally I'll be using Power BI, but thank you for your support on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the spoon.sh. If it doesn't help, maybe it explains...

> echo "I'm sorry, this Mac platform [$ARCH] is not yet supported!"
>
> echo "Please try starting using 'Data Integration 32-bit'
>
> or" echo "'Data Integration 64-bit' as appropriate."
>
> exit;

Comment: Added a bounty for you.