# Unable to install pentaho kettle on mac

Tags: macos, pentaho, kettle

I need to install just about any version that will work for some simple ETL jobs. I'm quite new to the mac world as I got one from my employer. I got pentaho 7.1 or 8.1 "installed" by unzipping the file to Applications and this seems to work at the first glimpse, but there are several follow up issues like crashing the whole application on right click in the sidebar.

I guess I need a clean installation/troubleshoot documentation for mac. I'm running the latest version of Java available for Mac which is 10.0.2 which might be the problem...

Is there any way I can test another Java Version without removing that one? I would be grateful for any documentation or help page that points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentaho 7.1 and 8.1 run using Java 8, so the crashes are most definitely caused by version 10 of Java!

In regards to using another version, you can use a program called Jenv to switch between Java versions on your mac.

First install homebrew (a package manager) using the command

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then run the command

```
brew install jenv
```

Next you need to install Java 8 JDK (Oracle website)

Once installed, add it to jenv using the command

```
jenv add /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/{YOUR_JAVA_VERSION}
```

Obviously replace {YOUR_JAVA_VERSION} with the actual directory of Java 8

Repeat for your Java 10 directory as well.

Run below command to view your added Java versions

```
jenv versions
```

You can change Java versions by running the following

```
jenv global oracle64-1.8.0.60
```

Replace oracle64-1.8.0.60 with whatever Java you want (The output of the jenv versions command)

Hope that helps!

[Homebrew for Mac](https://brew.sh/)

[Jenv](http://www.jenv.be/)

Comment: Everything seemed to have worked out properly. but the program is still crashing on right click in the sidebar.

jenv doctor shows:
[ERROR] Java binary in path is not in the jenv shims.
[ERROR] Please check your path, or try using /path/to/java/home is not a valid path to java installation.
 PATH : /usr/local/Cellar/jenv/0.4.4/libexec/libexec:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
[ERROR] Jenv is not loaded in your bash
[ERROR] To fix :  cat eval "$(jenv init -)" >> /Users/MYUSER/.bash_profile

Any plans?

Comment: Ok, I completely removed all java installations and just installed Java 8 with homebrew. Now pentaho 7.1 is working perfectly fine, no crashes anymore! As you pointed me in the right direction I will award you the correct answer :-) Thanks

Comment: Sorry about delay. I'm glad you got it fixed in the end. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

This question may be the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987752/cannot-run-pentaho-bi-server-on-mac/51265727#51265727). My answer (which was was not accepted as an answer, so I cannot flag your question as duplicate) was that the `spoon.sh` contains the following lines

```
echo "I'm sorry, this Mac platform [$ARCH] is not yet supported!"
echo "Please try starting using 'Data Integration 32-bit'
or" echo "'Data Integration 64-bit' as appropriate."
exit;
```

So my recommendation was to either follow Pentaho's recommendation to switch to java 32  bits (you can do this for DPI only), either to use Pentaho 7.1.

To switch to Java 32-bit, get the java software as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012722/get-oracle-java-1-8-in-windows-without-installing-it) and copy it in a directory nearby your PDI (I am using ../myPDI/Java). Then edit the `set-pentaho-env.sh` so that the `_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME` points to that `../myPDI/Java` and and `_JAVA_HOME` point to ~../MyPDI/Java/bin/java.exe`.

You will need a few (not many) trials before to get it. To ease your debug, you may adding the following lines at the end of the `set-pentaho-env.sh`, may be of a great help:

```
echo "DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=$_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME"
echo "DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=$_PENTAHO_JAVA"
$_PENTAHO_JAVA -version
```

as well as replacing **temporarily** the line `"$_PENTAHO_JAVA" $OPT -jar "$STARTUP" -lib $LIBPATH "${1+$@}"`with `"$_PENTAHO_JAVA" -version`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this solution? How do I change to 32 bit java on a Mac?